# CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests

Tags: c#

CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity2017\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar"

[image: problem-included]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, there is not enough detail for others to help. See here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1283008/android-unable-to-merge-android-manifest-error.html).

It seems that your Unity project is trying to compile with the wrong SDK version.

Change the **Minimal SDK version** under *Player Settings -> Other Settings*.

Comment: This is not the problem I think. Btw, I found a solution. Thanks for ur reply